# Vmware ESX 4.1 Not Responding

Tags: vmware-esx

My question is;I'm using Vmware ESX 4.1.But, that's gives me errors etc not responding.
My screenshot is here. http://img249.imageshack.us/f/hataz.png/
Also , Logs in definitions.

Default alarm to monitor host connection and power state

Default alarm to monitor host service console memory swap rates

Default alarm to monitor host memory usage

Default alarm for incorrectly configured VMKernel NIC

Default alarm to monitor network uplink redundancy degradation on a virtual switch

Default alarm to monitor loss of network uplink redundancy on a virtual switch

Default alarm to monitor network connectivity on a virtual switch

How can I get rid of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weirdly-written question indeed. Basically you have a problem with your vmkernel vswitch, i.e. it's a very basic networking issue - nothing to do with ESXi specifically. You need to check the following and in this order;

1. The cabling between the host, your client and any/all switches/routers in between.
2. Switch port config at the host end, are you trunking?
3. The basic IP stuff - i.e. are NMs and DGs correct at both ends, can it ping etc.

What you should also do is use the built-in ESXi network test option on the host, it tests pinging its DG, DNS servers and does a forward/reserve check on itself - all by hitting one enter key :)

Come back to us with more details when you can.

Answer (score -1):

You need to adjust the default alarm values. Use VMware's guild [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsp40/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#context=admin&file=c_working_with_alarms.html)

Comment: Huh? I'm really not with you on this one, can you explain more please